# How to find out which Rust dependency added a dynamically linked library

Tags: rust, dynamic-linking

I have a fairly large project with many dependencies. And I'd like the resulting binary to use as few dynamically linked libraries as possible. I just checked the resulting binary and saw:

```
$ ldd target/debug/foo
libssl.so.1.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007f1f2100e000)
...
```

I don't know why my binary dynamically links to `libssl`, so I would like to investigate. I know that Rust crates that add these links need to [print some special lines](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#outputs-of-the-build-script) in their build script. But now I'm lost: how would I easily find out which of my many hundreds of indirect dependencies (i.e. Rust crates) added this dynamic link? Is there a good general solution?

Comment: Ok I guess `cargo clean && cargo build -vv 2>/dev/null | grep 'rustc-link'` is a solution... But I'll leave this open as (a) maybe there is a better solution and (b) I'm not sure what `rustc-link*` outputs I'm looking for exactly.

Comment: In the case of `libssl`, it's likely that it got added by `openssl-sys`, and you can use `cargo tree` to find out which dependency chain caused it to be included.

Comment: @Jmb Thanks, it was indeed `openssl-sys`. However, I think it would be useful if there would be a general answer to this question to help others in different situations. I was confused that there was no easy guide on how to do that yet.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if there is a better way, but this worked for me:

```
cargo clean && cargo build -vv 2>/dev/null | grep 'rustc-link-lib'
```

---

Some explanation:

- We are interested in [the output of the build scripts](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#outputs-of-the-build-script) of all dependencies.
- `cargo clean`: force reexecuting all build scripts.
- `cargo build -vv`: show output of build scripts.
- `2>/dev/null`: ignore stderr of `cargo build` (it's very noisy otherwise)
- `grep`: filtering for relevant lines.

The command should result in some output like this:

```
[libz-sys 1.1.8] cargo:rustc-link-lib=z
[openssl-sys 0.9.75] cargo:rustc-link-lib=ssl
[openssl-sys 0.9.75] cargo:rustc-link-lib=crypto
```

Note that not all printed lines are necessarily a dynamic link to a library (e.g. there is `rustc-link-lib=static=...`).

Comment: Note that this will miss libraries specified with [`cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=foo`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html?highlight=rustc-link-lib#rustc-link-lib) or those specified with a [`#[link]` attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/external-blocks.html#the-link-attribute)

Comment: @Jmb Very good points. I adjusted my answer to account for the first thing, but the `#[link]` attribute is indeed still a problem. I would love for someone to come up with a better answer also addressing that.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a good general solution

There is no *magic* to these dependencies -- every dependency listed by `ldd` comes from the `DT_NEEDED` entry of the main binary, or one of its dependencies.

To list the "first level" of dependencies, look at the output of `readelf -d target/debug/foo | grep NEEDED`.

If `libssl.so.1.1` is not in that list, repeat (recursively) for each library which is in the "first level" list.

This could be fairly easily scripted.

Another alternative is to run `LD_DEBUG=files ldd target/debug/foo`, which should produce entries similar to:

```
 file=libssl.so.1.1 [0];  needed by ...
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I'm trying to find out which Rust dependency (i.e. a crate from crates.io) in my dependency graph is responsible for adding the dynamic link. The two commands you provide don't show anything Rust related. I edited my question a bit to hopefully clarify

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt Once you know which library added dependency in `libssl.so.1.1`, it should be trivial to find out which Rust dependency added that library using whatever Rust tool is appropriate for that.