# how to find out which native libraries to link in buiding C-mixed Rust static library

Tags: c, rust, static-libraries, static-linking

I want to creat a static library using Rust, and then use it in a C program. The library is expected to be *self-contained* (i.e. all its dependencies are self-contained).

At first, `crate-type = ["staticlib"]` was added in `Cargo.toml`. But this methods seemed to worked only in simple cases, where Rust code only contains basic functions and no external crates.

For a more complex Rust code, the above method may fail to build a *self-contained* library. In this case, the library can be built, but it cannot be used by C program.

I also have learnt that one can build a *self-contained* library by typing

`RUSTFLAGS='-C target-feature=+crt-static' cargo build --release --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`

However, the libaray failed to be built.

```
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
|
 = note: LC_ALL="C" PATH="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

 /usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status> note: some `extern` functions couldn't be found; some native libraries may need to be installed or have their path specified

  = note: some `extern` functions couldn't be found; some native libraries may need to be installed or have their path specified
  = note: use the `-l` flag to specify native libraries to link
  = note: use the `cargo:rustc-link-lib` directive to specify the native libraries to link with Cargo (see https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#cargorustc-link-libkindname)>
```

I have also read the building part of [the official instruction](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html), from which I understand the native libraries should be linked to Rust cargo build, looking like

`RUSTFLAGS='-C target-feature=+crt-static -L /path/to/nativelibrary' cargo build --release --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`

Supposing that my Rust code uses dozens of external crates, each of which may also has its own dependencies, I really don't know what to fill in `/path/to/nativelibrary`.

Questions:

1. Is there a more automatic way to generate a completely *self-contained* library?
2. If the way by setting`/path/to/nativelibrary` is unavoidable, how to find out which native libraries to link?

---

## Update

Till now, I've found three possible ways, unfunny.

- `cargo clean && cargo build -vv 2>/dev/null | grep 'rustc-link-lib'` can help find out which native libraries are required ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73610525/how-to-find-out-which-rust-dependency-added-a-dynamically-linked-library)).
- crate `pkg-config` can help probe for specific libraries once you know their names ([see here](https://crates.io/crates/pkg-config)).
- crate `cross` may be useful to help build truely static binaries ([see here](https://crates.io/crates/cross)), but I didn't succeed with it.

Comment: `/path/to/nativelibrary` is for _C libraries_ that you want to link with your Rust code. For Rust libraries, Cargo already adds the necessary `-L` options automatically.